# Selenium: получить загруженное изображение

Tags: python, веб-программирование, html, selenium

Здравствуйте.

Пишу небольшое приложение на Python с использованием Selenium.
Необходимо как-то получить изображение с загруженной веб-страницы.

Вариант получить ссылку и сделать дополнительный запрос не подходит, т.к. сервер на той стороне фильтрует такие запросы и отправляет другое изображение.

Хотелось бы получить именно то изображение, которое загружается при загрузке страницы.
Скажите, это можно как-то сделать?

Answer (score 1):

лично я доставал следующим макаром:

1. сделать скриншот браузера
2. обрезать скриншот до размеров елемента с координатами елемента и присвоить в битмап.

но есть еще вариант более коректный -- взять урл и загрузить отдельно битмап с него. Тогда изображение получится коректным и полностью соответствующее оригиналу.

Answer (score 0):

А изображение нужно именно в том исходном качестве?

Если все равно, то можно снять скриншот со всей страницы, определить координаты и размер изображения и вырезать из полного скриншота изображение. Не знаю насколько будет подругому на питоне, вот пример на Java

```
 RemoteWebElement element= ((RemoteWebElement) driver.switchTo().defaultContent().findElement(yourElement));
        File temp = driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        Point point = element.getCoordinates().inViewPort();
        Dimension size = element.getSize();
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(temp);
            return image.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(), size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
        } catch (IOException io) {
            System.out.println("Can't read screenshot in buffer");
            return null;
        }
```

А вообще можно просто залезть во временную папку профиля браузера и оттуда вытащить картинку. Путь к папке профиля получить можно так:

```
List<String> profileDirs = Lists.newArrayList("anonymous*webdriver-profile",
                "userprofile*copy", "seleniumSslSupport*");
        File tmpDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
        FilenameFilter profileDirsFilter = new WildcardFileFilter(profileDirs);
        List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
        files.addAll(Arrays.asList(tmpDir.listFiles(profileDirsFilter)));
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    List<File> files1 = new ArrayList<>();
        files1.addAll(Arrays.asList(tmpDir.listFiles(profileDirsFilter)));
        files1.removeAll(files);
        System.out.print(files1.get(0)); //temp folder
```

А из кеша профиля уже можно попробовать достать, в открытом виде, конечно, они лежать не будут, но логику уловить я думаю можно.